# Does resonance apply to NO₂⁺?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, resonance

My textbook said $\ce{NO2+}$ and $\ce{NO2-}$ both have resonance structures, now I am a little bit confused since I cannot figure out the resonance structure for $\ce{NO2+}$.

What is it?

Answer (score 5):

In the following below, please interpret formal charges as marked below the atom.
$$\ce{O=N=O} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ce{O\equiv N-O} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ce{O-N \equiv O} $$
$$\ \ \ \ \ + \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ + \ \ +\ \ - \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -\ \ +\ \ + $$

The triply charged species are valid resonance forms, but very likely are small contributors.

Comment: Triple bonds can be made with MathJax using \equiv for the equivalence symbol. `$\equiv$` renders as $\equiv$

Comment: The last two resonance structures are identical.

Comment: @Dissenter, no, they are not identical.  They are equivalent.  Which nitrogen is which matters for resonance structures in that both can have a triple bond, and there must be one structure that indicates a triple bond on each.

Comment: Shouldn't they be identical because rotating one 180 degrees gives the other?

Comment: When writing resonance structures, the atoms must be absolutely fixed in space.  Perhaps you're muddling chirality into the concept?